# In SASS I want to change the background color of every even row of items

Tags: html, css, sass

In SASS I want to change the background color of every even row of items.

**This is my HTML show the grid view of a row of 3 items**

```
<ul>
 <li><li> <li><li> <li><li>
 <li><li> <li><li> <li><li>
 <li><li> <li><li> <li><li>
 <li><li> <li><li> <li><li>
</ul>
```

**This is my SASS attempt:**

```
.ul {
  li {
    background: $white;

    &:nth-child(3) {
        background: red;
    }
  }
}
```

**Problem**: is the above example only does the third item.

**Outcome I want:**

Each row has 3 li's
I want every second row of li's to have a background color of red.
Is there some maths I can do on **:nth-child** in order to achieve this in SASS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This one works:

```
ul {
  li {
    background: white;

        &:nth-child(6n-2), &:nth-child(6n-1),&:nth-child(6n) {
        background: red;
    }
  }
}
```

Please also notice that you have `.ul` instead of `ul`

Comment: @AngularM please mark answer as accepted so it will be easier for users with similar questions to decide if solution is acceptable for them